# Launch single Application for multiple file selection via Windows Context Menu

Tags: java, windows, windows-explorer

I hava a Java Application which integrates itself into the Windows Explorer Context Menu by adding a registry key (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\[AppName]\command`).
This works finde if exactly one file is selected and the application started via context menu. Sadly, if multiple files are selected, the application is started once for each selected file.

Now, my question is: How can I achieve that the java application is started once with all files passed to this single instance?
I know that this can be achieved by using the "Send To" Option of the context menu but I need to integrate it directly to the context menu.

Comment: Could you show what you added to the registry key? I guess your Java application is using args to get the selected file?

Comment: you're right! I´m using args to read the parameters passed to the application. I added "javaw.exe" -jar "C:\Foldername\Appname.jar" %1 to the registry.